android: cannot navigate back to the parent navItem
I have a NavGraph like this in the NavController
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:name="com.bradley.kon.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_dashboard"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_projects"
    android:name="com.bradley.kon.ui.projects.ProjectsFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_projects"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_projects" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_locations"
    android:name="com.bradley.kon.ui.locations.LocationsFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_locations"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_locations" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
    android:name="com.bradley.kon.ui.settings.SettingsFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_settings"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />

So inside ProjectsFragment there is a ListView, such that when the Item is clicked on the ListView, it navigates to the LocationsFragment with a bundle like this
NavController navController =
            Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);

navController.navigate(R.id.nav_locations, projectBundle);

So upon reaching the LocationsFragment I cannot go to the ProjectsFragment from the NavController. (See in the GIF)

What am I missing?

Check nav_host_fragment_content_main is properly set up in your activity_main.xml file. Also add action in your navigation graph for navigating back to ProjectsFragment from LocationsFragment.

You better add a navigation action for handle the navigation properly

I'm not very pro at Android dev, I know I can add  inside a fragment to provide the dest. I did that, still it causes the same issue.
But if I press the back button, everything goes to normal state.
